# Jquery get number of nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server-side

Consider a dynamic dropdown-menu. Because of creating this code server side I don't know the exact number of `li` situated in `div 'sub'`.Example HTML output:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Videos</a>
        <div id="sub">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#">Acting</a></li>                                     
                <li><a href="#">Animals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </li>
```

The following script should give the number of `li` in the in `div id="sub"`

```
$(function() {
        $('.tabMenu li a').click(function() {
        currentLink = $(this);
       //Get number of children elements
       alert(currentLink.children().size());
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   alert(currentLink.parent().find('li').size());
```

Answer (score 1):

First: where is your `.tabMenu` in your code?

Try with:

```
.length;
```

### [Working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/62RKa/)

```
$('.tabMenu li a').click(function() {
    currentLink = $(this);
    alert(currentLink.parents('ul').children('li').length); 
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need to specify li in the children as it should return only the first level of elements under the parent element. Since the ul is a structured element (should only contain li elements), it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is get the parent container of the li element, then see how many children it has:

```
$(function() {
    $('.tabMenu li a').click(function() {
   // Get the parent ul of the current link
   var currentLinkParent = $(this).parents("ul:first");

   alert(currentLinkParent.children().size() );

});
```